# Can someone review my implementation of a KeyValuePair?

Tags: java

```
public class KeyValuePair implements Comparable {

    private Comparable key;
    private Object value;

    public KeyValuePair(Comparable key, Object value) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object item) throws ClassCastException {
    if (!(item instanceof KeyValuePair)) {
        throw new ClassCastException("A KeyValuePair object was expected");
    }
    return this.key.compareTo(((KeyValuePair) item).key);
    }

    public Comparable getKey() {
    return this.key;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
    return this.value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't need to throw `ClassCastException` explicitly; it would be thrown automatically by the JVM if the cast actually fails.

However, you shouldn't have to deal with casting at all if you use Java Generics properly.

```
public class KeyValuePair<K extends Comparable<K>, V>
        implements Comparable<KeyValuePair<K, V>> {

    private K key;
    private V value;

    public KeyValuePair(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(KeyValuePair<K, V> item) {
        return this.key.compareTo(item.key);
    }

    public K getKey() {
        return this.key;
    }

    public V getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** As @ortang points out, there's more work to be done!  Since the key and value are immutable, marking them `final` is helpful.  Also, the class needs to override `.equals()`, and when that happens, `.hashCode()` needs to be overridden too.  Finally, it may be worthwhile to handle some odd cases in `.compareTo()`.

```
public class KeyValuePair<K extends Comparable<K>, V> implements Comparable<KeyValuePair<K, V>> {

    private final K key;
    private final V value;

    public KeyValuePair(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    // Arbitrarily decide to sort null keys first.  Values are disregarded for
    // the purposes of comparison.
    @Override
    public int compareTo(KeyValuePair<K, V> item) {
        if (this.key == null) {
            return (item.key == null) ? 0 : -1;
        } else {
            return this.key.compareTo(item.key);
        }
    }

    public K getKey() {
        return this.key;
    }

    public V getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == null || !this.getClass().equals(other.getClass())) {
            return false;
        }
        KeyValuePair item = (KeyValuePair)other;
        return (this.key == null   ? item.key == null   : this.key.equals(item.key)) &&
               (this.value == null ? item.value == null : this.value.equals(item.value));
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return ((this.key == null)   ? 0 : this.key.hashCode()) ^
               ((this.value == null) ? 0 : this.value.hashCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: Also mark the `key` and `value` as `final`, maybe even the class to be immutable and implement at least `equals()` as it is [required](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).